# Laravel - edit data before passing to view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm looking for a way to edit data before passing them to view.

Quick example (just to demonstrate):
Let's say I am passing variable `$name` to a view through controller. I would like to use something to pass another variable `$message` which would contain `Hello $name`, so for example *Hello John*, if variable `$name` would be John.

I don't want to send this second variable in controller, because I'm gonna use a lot of controllers, views and the thing that I want to do with the data is rather complicated.

I need to use this for both variables `view("foobar", ["foo" => "bar"])` and sessions `view("foobar")->with("foo", "bar")`.

I've tried to use both *Middleware* and *Service Provider* but the problem was I couldn't access the sent data.

The only possible solution I can think of now is to use *View layout* which I'm going to *include* into every view and which is gonna transform the variables (using something like `<? $message = "Hello $name"; ?>` in the view), but this doesn't seem like the right MVC solution for me.

Thank you all for your answers!

Comment: Perhaps accessor? https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Comment: What about `View::share('foo', $foo);`? You can use it anywhere outside your controller and `$foo` will render in the returned view.

Comment: Regarding your nested message, you can do `view('message', 'Hello %s');` in your controller and in your view call `{{ sprintf($message, $foo) }}`.

Comment: @Kyslik - thanks, but that's not really what I'm looking for
@MarcoFlorian - I've tried `View::share` and this is exacly what I'm looking for, but my problem is that I don't know how to _get_ the data passed from controller to manipulate them. I need to get variables passed to view before passing my new variable.
Also about `sprintf`- the variable I want to pass is an array, so I don't think this is the way to do so (the example with _Hello $name_ was just an example, in reality I'm going to work with an array)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass session data and multiple variables, do this:

```
session()->flash('message', 'some message');

return view('foobar', [
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'second' => 'something'
]);
```

**Update**

If I understood you correctly, you want to use [view composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#view-composers).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's not exacly what I want. I want to get variable/session content somewhere before rendering the view and then pass new variable to the view.
Basicly I want something like Middleware in which I can access data sent to view and send new data.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for view composer (link is in updated answer)? Can you tell me why do you need this? Maybe there is simpler solution. For example, you can use `session()` to get data in view directly.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried _view composer_, but I couldn't access sessions and variables.
I need this because I am sending data about result of some action (i.e. _post deleted_ etc). It is either an array - message and type (success, error, warning,...) or string (only text of the message with default type success).
1. I need to convert the string to an array (add type automatically)
2. I need to generate coresponding icon (i. e. success = check) and color (ie. success = green, error = red). 
Do you have any idea how to do this out of the template?